# After click on a button, count x seconds and then redirect to a specific link using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What i want to do is exactly what i mentioned in the question title. I have a form with a submit button. Is it possible using jQuery to redirect the user to a specific link page after 5 seconds starting count from the moment this user clicked the submit button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use setTimeout and window.location

```
setTimeout(function(event) {
  window.location.href = url
    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

The below code do exactly what you want:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = 'http://new-url';
    }, 5000);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for JavaScript's `setTimeout` functionality.
The first thing you'll need to do is prevent the form submitting immediately (default behaviour) with `event.preventDefault()` otherwise nothing will be executed.

Check out this example with comments, Should provide a bit more information for you;

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="text-field" placeholder="Enter something" />
    <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(event) { // pass an event argument so we can call preventDefault
        event.preventDefault(); // call event.preventDefault to stop form submitting immediately 

        setTimeout(function() { // Set up a setTimeout operation
            console.log('form submitted after timeout');
            window.location.href = '/';
        }, 5000); /// 5000 ms == 5s
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) in order to achieve what you want to achieve. `setTimeout` is a function which takes two parameters:

- a callback function
- the timeout in milliseconds

#### Callback

A callback `function` is a `function` to be executed when a given event happens. In our case the event is that a given amount of time elapsed. This is how your callback could look like:

```
function redirect() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
}
```

#### Timeout

The timeout is the second parameter of the function. It defines the amount of time to elapse before the callback is being called. In our case you want 5 seconds to wait before the callback is executed, so the timeout will be 5000 milliseconds.

#### Usage

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
}, 5000);
```

or

```
function redirect() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
}
setTimeout(redirect, 5000);
```

Either way it is elegant to wrap a `function` around the solution and call the `function` on the `onclick`.